# convert Powershell Return Values in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

i want to filter a Property from a PSObject and convert it to a string Value for further use.
In my case the return value is a litte bit complex and does not allow .ToString() Convertion.

I have fount a solution, but this will only work in this case, and i can get a lot of errors if the input values are changing.

So ist there a more generic way to get this values?

```
using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
    ps.AddCommand("get-help").AddArgument("C:\\Users\\kritzinger\\Work\\test.ps1");
    Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = ps.Invoke();
    foreach (PSObject outputItem  in PSOutput)
    {
        dynamic description = outputItem.Properties["description"].Value;

        // not working
        string foo = description.ToString();
        // foo = "System.Management.Automation.PSObject[]"

        foreach (dynamic item in description)
        {
            // not working
            string bar = item.ToString();
            // bar = ""

            // working!
            string moo = item.Text;
            // moo = "here is the description of the poweshell script"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
string foo = Convert.ToString(description).ToString();
```

It will do the trick!

Comment: sorry Convert.ToString results the same as .ToString Methode.
Convert.ToString(description).ToString() gives an error that the methode .ToString is not valid.